# Cloning div with vue

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
    <b-form @submit.prevent="Submit" class="mb-5">
        <div class="inputArea" v-for="input in inputs" :key="input.id">
        <b-form-group label-cols-sm="2" label="Solution (EN)">
        <ckeditor :editor="ckeditor" v-model="form.body.en" :config="ckeditorConfig"></ckeditor>
        <div v-if="errors['body.en']">
            <div v-for="err in errors['body.en']" :key="err">
                <small class="text-danger">{{ err }}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-form-group label-cols-sm="2" label="Body (FR)">
        <ckeditor :editor="ckeditor" v-model="form.body.np" :config="ckeditorConfig"></ckeditor>
        <div v-if="errors['body.np']">
            <div v-for="err in errors['body.np']" :key="err">
                <small class="text-danger">{{ err }}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-form-group label-cols-sm="2" label="Body (IT)">
        <ckeditor :editor="ckeditor" v-model="form.body.in" :config="ckeditorConfig"></ckeditor>
        <div v-if="errors['body.in']">
            <div v-for="err in errors['body.in']" :key="err">
                <small class="text-danger">{{ err }}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        </b-form-group>
        </div>
        <b-form-group label="" label-cols-sm="2">
            <b-button type="button" class="text-white" variant="dark" @click="addRow">Add row</b-button>
        </b-form-group>    

        <b-form-group label="" label-cols-sm="2">
            <b-button type="submit" class="text-white" variant="dark">Submit</b-button>
        </b-form-group>
    </b-form>
</template>
<style lang="scss">

</style>
<script>
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
export default {
    name: 'Interaction',
    components: {
        ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    data(){
        return{
            counter: 0,
            inputs: [
                {
                en: '',
                np: '',
                in: '',
            }],
            form: {
                
                body: [
                {
                    en: '',
                    np: '',
                    in: '',
                }
                ],
                
            },
            errors: {},
            ckeditorData: '<p></p>',
            ckeditorConfig: {
                // The configuration of the editor
            },
            ckeditor: ClassicEditor
        }
    },
    methods: {            
        Submit(){
            this.storing = true
            this.errors = {}
            var self = this
            axios.post('/this-is-a-post-url', this.form)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response)
            })
            
        },
        addRow() {
        this.inputs.push({
            en: '',
            it: '',
            fr: '',
            id: `${++this.counter}`,
            value: '',
        });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I will have array coming in the `body` name so I am trying to to clone the clone body on a click of a button which has a function `AddRow`. I want to clone the three fields `en,np,in` and I want it work like normal html works in this. Example when we clone html form it create input field like so `<input name="body['en'][0]">` and when we clone another time it creates something like this `<input name="body['en'][1]">`.

I have the above code, it clones the body but it also clones the added text before cloning. I want to add an empty field while cloning and also want to update `v-model`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below example:
https://codepen.io/telen/pen/OeNZVV

```
<main class="container">
<form id="app" data-apartments='[{ "price": "23000", "rooms": "12" }, { "price": "42000", "rooms": "32" }]'>
    <h1>
        Dynamic apartment forms
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" v-on:click="addNewApartment" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                Add +
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            Would you like add more apartments?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="(apartment, index) in apartments">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <button type="button" v-on:click="removeApartment(index)" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">
                    Rem -
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label>Price (HUF)</label>
                <input v-model="apartment.price" type="number"
                       name="apartments[][price]" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label>Rooms (PCS)</label>
                <input v-model="apartment.rooms" type="number"
                       name="apartments[][rooms]" class="form-control" placeholder="Rooms">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="sumbitForm" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            Open the console (F12) and see the result
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</form>
```

JS:

```
    window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    apartment: {
      price: '',
      rooms: ''
    },
    apartments: [],
  },
  mounted: function () {
    /*
     * The "data-apartments" could come from serverside (already saved apartments)
     */
    this.apartments = JSON.parse(this.$el.dataset.apartments)
  },
  methods: {
    addNewApartment: function () {
      this.apartments.push(Vue.util.extend({}, this.apartment))
    },
    removeApartment: function (index) {
      Vue.delete(this.apartments, index);
    },
    sumbitForm: function () {
      /*
       * You can remove or replace the "submitForm" method.
       * Remove: if you handle form sumission on server side.
       * Replace: for example you need an AJAX submission.
       */
      console.info('<< Form Submitted >>')
      console.info('Vue.js apartments object:', this.apartments)
      window.testSumbit()
    }
  }
})

/*
 * This is not Vue.js code, just a bit of jQuery to test what data would be submitted.
 */
window.testSumbit = function () {
  if (!window.jQuery) {
    console.warn('jQuery not present!')
    return false
  }
  console.info('Submitted (serverside) array:', jQuery('form').serializeJSON())
}
```